# jQuery doesn't work when used in a Chrome Extension on a https page

Tags: jquery, https, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying my hand at a Chrome extension. On a "regular" page, I can seem to fetch whatever that is I need ( `('.myclass')`, for instance).

On an https page, it returns null. I'm loading jQuery from my extensions folder as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947510/load-jquery-into-a-chrome-extension). I thought I was doing something wrong in my extensions code, but running `$(this)` on a "regular" page ( such as SO homepage) returns all properties/methods, but on a a https page - this returns null.

Is jQuery not being injected into the page?

FTR: The https page I'm working on is Google Adsense. Below is the portion on my `manifest.json`:

```
 "background_page": "ga.html",
   "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["https://www.google.com/adsense/*"],
     "js": ["jquery.js", "cnt.js"]
   }
   ],
  "permissions": ["https://www.google.com/adsense/*"]
```

---

To add from comments: My cnt.js contains just this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert('Hi!');
 });
```

Strange thing is that the alert pops up before the page load is complete on Adsense page, which for other pages, it pops up after the load is complete

Comment: Extensions don't work on Google pages as far as I know...  Or maybe it's just they don't work within the extension gallery pages...  Either way you might want to check.

Comment: @Endophage they don't work on Extension gallery pages, IIRC

Comment: look at the src of your jquery file on your `<script>` tag it too might need to change to `https` instead of normal `http` :) otherwise use a CDN http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery i'd personally check on firebug if the jquery file has been loaded successfully and that its not empty :)

Comment: I don't have adsense account but I tried it on `https://www.google.com/analytics/` and it worked.

Comment: @Serg - no dice, even on Analytics it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and inject the page at document_end? Perhaps there is a conflict in adsense with jQuery? Can you check in the console and see if there are any $ mapped already.

For now, try adding the document_end:

```
 "background_page": "ga.html",
 "content_scripts": [{
   "matches": ["https://www.google.com/adsense/*"],
   "js": ["jquery.js", "cnt.js"],
   "run_at": "document_end"
 }],
"permissions": ["https://www.google.com/adsense/*"]
```

Comment: thanks, but it does not work :( How can I verify `any $ mapped already.` ?

Comment: You type "$" in the adsense web inspector. In cnt.js, just put alert('ping'), reload your extension, and see if a alert will be shown when you visit https://www.google.com/adsense/*

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that the alert was popping up before Adsense page loads, however for other sites, the alert pops up after the page loads. The alert was added to my cnt.js, which as of now contains `$(document).ready(function() { alert('Hi!');});`